# Nginx: create a location to redirect to another location

Tags: nginx, nginx-reverse-proxy, nginx-location

I'm trying to redirect a location to another location, but for some reason it doesn't work. My nginx service is running under a [Docker container](https://hub.docker.com/_/nginx) on `8080:80` port.

I have `/portal` that shows my web application correctly and I would like nginx redirects from `/` to `/portal`. I've tried some approaches using `location /` or `location = /`, but with no success.

The `/portal` can be accessed normally by

```
http://localhost:8080/portal
```

but for some reason when I access

```
http://localhost:8080/
```

the browser redirects to

```
https://localhost/portal
```

instead of redirecting to:

```
http://localhost:8080/portal
```

**Locations:**

```
upstream webportal {
    server portal_container:8080;
}

location / {
  return 301 /portal;
}

location /portal {
    proxy_set_header        Host            $host;
    proxy_set_header        X-Real-IP       $remote_addr;
    proxy_set_header        X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    proxy_pass http://webportal;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I was able to fix the problem by adding [`absolute_redirect off;`](https://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#absolute_redirect) to my location:

```
location / {
    absolute_redirect off;
    return 301 /portal;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I struggled with this problem for a bit today. Building on previous answer to extend the solution to kubernetes pod...

1. Angular app was is deployed behind an nginx server listening on port 80.
2. It was deployed as a pod called 'ngapp' in a kubernetes-cluster in a namespace called 'frontend'.

```
deployment.yaml
===============

apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  labels:
    app: ngapp
  name: ngapp
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: ngapp
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: ngapp
    spec:
      containers:
      - image:  mydomain.com/ngapp:v1.0.0
        name: ngapp
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  labels:
    app: ngapp
  name: ngapp
spec:
  type: NodePort
  ports:
  - name: ngapp-port
    port: 4200 #Service Port
    targetPort: 80 #Port to forward to
    nodePort: 30001 #Port exposed to the external world (laptop browser)
  selector:
    app: ngapp

This meant the following:

1) fellow containers/pods can access nginx server at ngapp.frontend.svc.cluster.local:4200 
(note that this pod is deployed  in a namespace called 'frontend', 
and hence it is included in the DNS name)

2) host (your laptop browser for instance) can access the nginx server at localhost:30001

3) k8s c-m (container mgr) and core-dns (name->ip resolution) servers in 
the control plain of k8s do the magic to send the requests to port 80 on 
the 'ngapp' container (where nginx is listening for requests)
```

3. ngapp was build with following command (to enable the base-uri)

ng build --base-href "/ngapp/" -c "k8s"

4. The code was deployed at /apps/dist/ngapp/ inside the pod

following is the nginx configuration

```
All the files referenced here are in ngapp pod.

/etc/nginx/nginx.conf
=====================

user  nginx;
worker_processes  auto;
error_log  /var/log/nginx/error.log notice;
pid        /var/run/nginx.pid;

events {
    worker_connections  1024;
}

http {
    include       /etc/nginx/mime.types;
    default_type  application/octet-stream;
    log_format  main  '$remote_addr - $remote_user [$time_local] "$request" '
                      '$status $body_bytes_sent "$http_referer" '
                      '"$http_user_agent" "$http_x_forwarded_for"';
    access_log  /var/log/nginx/access.log  main;
    sendfile        on;
    keepalive_timeout  65;
    include /etc/nginx/conf.d/*.conf;
}


/etc/nginx/conf.d/ngapp.conf
============================

server {
    listen       80;
    listen  [::]:80;
    server_name  localhost;

    location /ngapp/ {
        root /apps/dist;
        try_files $uri $uri/ /ngapp/index.html;
    }

    location / {
        absolute_redirect off;
        return 301 /ngapp/;
    }

    error_page   500 502 503 504  /50x.html;
    location = /50x.html {
        root   /usr/share/nginx/html;
    }
}
```

with this setup, I was successfully able to access the SPA website at:

```
http://localhost:30001
http://localhost:30001/
http://localhost:30001/ngapp
http://localhost:30001/ngapp/
```